# ignore file extesion in webforms routehanlder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following route handler to route urls in a .net 4.0 solution. The route handler, by default, ignores files that exists, and it's exactly what I need because I don't want to map css files, js files, images files, etc.

A change in the webconfig (adding the customerros section) forced me to notice a bug. If there's a link for a image, and the image doesn't exists, the url is mapped, causing a lot of trouble (errors).

Now what I need is to completely ignore a file extension (js, css, jpg, gif, etc) or, preferable, only map .aspx files. But I'm not sure how to do that.

ps: the website is based on user uploads, a percentual of broken links will always exists.

```
public class RouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public RouteHandler(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Page page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_path, typeof(Page)) as Page;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> i in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[i.Key.Replace("*", "")] = i.Value;
        }

        return page;
    }
}

routes.Add("somename", new Route("folder/insidefolder", null, null, new RouteHandler("~/folder-insidefolder.aspx")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following line solves the image problem (need more tests):

```
routes.Ignore("{*images}", new { images = @".*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|ico|ICO)(\?.*)?" });
```